# How to connect to Java TServlet from nodejs thrift client?

Tags: java, node.js, thrift

I've been trying to connect nodejs and Java servlet applications using thrift.

The things that you can specify in TServlet constructor are Processor factory and a handler, which is implementation of specific IFace interface. As I can see, when using thrift in nodejs, you can only use TBufferedTransport, and TFramedTransport, the later being the default.

I tried both, and none seem to work. I also experimented on TServlet side, and tried to use TCompactProtocol, TBinaryProtocol and TJSONProtocol, but nothing helped.

I can get a client to connect, but he doesn't seem to be hitting the servlet.

So how can I tell node to use transport that is compatible with TServlet, or tell servlet to use Protocol that is compatible with anything nodejs thrift client can use?

(Just to make things clear, i can hit java handler from node when using TServer in java, but i don't want to start TServer, because java app would be deployed on cloud, so port binding is a pain, and usage of long running threads is questionable)

Comment: Was any progress made on this? I'm trying to solve the same problem: related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764864/use-apache-thrift-nodejs-client-over-http

Comment: Sorry for the long time it took to respond, and for the response itself :) . Unfortunately I haven't been able to make this work, so I just deployed TServer implementation on Amazon EC2, that allows long running threads. This was some demo related to mu grad thesis, so I didn't matter that much at the end.