# Use Apache Thrift NodeJS Client over HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, thrift

Is there any clean way to connect a NodeJS Apache Thrift client to a Thrift Servlet over HTTP?  I've tried implementing this by replacing the Connection with an `http.ClientRequest` object, then binding to the connect event on the underlying socket and re-emitting this from the client request object so that Thrift will send the queued bytes, but this ultimately results in parsing errors.

Is there any clean way to use HTTP for a NodeJS Thrift client right now?

Comment: There has been some (unreleased) work around NodeJS support lately. I'd recommend to try the current trunk and/or ask that question on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @JensG -- it does look like they added HTTP server support for NodeJS, but the client library is still relying on the ``net`` package  (thus the TCP protocol, with no HTTP on top).  Looks like a lot of the other languages have an HTTP client available (including the browser JS package, relaying on either jQuery or native AJAX support), so I may have to just see what I can model off these.